# Reading from a BufferedReader (readLine) returns null?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I am currently trying to read a `String` from a `BufferedReader` but cant find a way to do this...

Of course I tried

```
BufferedReader inStream = null;
inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
String test = inStream.readLine();
```

However the result turns out as null when trying to print to a screen even though the `BufferedReader inStream` is equal to some kind of message.

Comment: Are you sure there is actual content in the inputstream?

Comment: The first line might be empty...

Comment: Attila's comment is important - `BufferedReader.readLine()` will return null when end of stream is reached.

Comment: @appclay - an empty line yields an empty string

Answer (score 11):

Based on [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), the `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` only when the end of the stream is reached.  This means if the first call to `readLine()` returns `null`, there was nothing in the input stream to begin with.

Comment: But there definitely is as when I print out the bufferedreader it shows me what I pass to it from my other pc...

Comment: Does the `readLine` return `null` or an empty string?  That is, when you print it out, do you see "nothing" (empty string) or the word "null"

Comment: How are you printing out the `BufferedReader`? Show some code.

Comment: Is it possible the client puts a null value (resulting in a string `"null"`) on the stream first, a newline then some additional (non-null) value?  The code you linked to does not agree with what you say is happening unless the "null" you see is the actual string on the stream: the letters 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l' are sent.  Check by assigning the result of `readLine` to a String and test it for null: `String tmp = inStream.readLine(); if (tmp == null) { System.out.println("got real null); } else { System.out.println("got the word: " + tmp); }`