# All possible reasons for readline() to be null

Tags: java, url

Code piece:

```
    HttpURLConnection url = new HttpURLConnection(new URL("myurl"));
    InputStream connInputStream = null;
    try 
           {
              connInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(connInputStream));
               boolean matchFound = false;
               String strLine = in.readLine();
    }
...
```

In this code piece I get strLine = null, Which means in.readLine is null.
What are the possible reasons that in.readline can come as null.
This code piece does not throw any null pointer exception.

Can this case arise because of the time lag in reading url source to the stream ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from a BufferedReader (readLine) returns null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202515/reading-from-a-bufferedreader-readline-returns-null)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one reason: [you've reached the end of the underlying stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). What the end of stream is depends on the underlying stream implementation.