# What triggers a Socket's InputStream to close (or reach end of stream), and simply yield null?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, bufferedreader

It sounds like an odd question, but I've been toying around with Server/Client Java work using Sockets. Something interesting I found is that when I ran a separate thread for the client to read lines from the server through the following code:

```
        String servIn = null;
        boolean isFinished = false;
        while(!isFinished){

            servIn = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(servIn);

        }
```

When the all the reading I needed done ended (in other words, I no longer wrote to the Socket in the code), this code produced an endless stream of "null". After doing a bit of research, based on [Reading from a BufferedReader (readLine) returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202515/reading-from-a-bufferedreader-readline-returns-null), I concluded that once all the methods had run, the end of stream was reached.

I found this odd, because I never explicitly told the stream to close at the end, and there are times in the code when it needs to hang on (BufferedReader, from a Socket) readLine() to wait for a (PrintWriter, from a Socket) writer.println() on another end of the code, and vice versa. From what I understand of readLine() and println(), they seem to wait until the respective other method is ready. This makes me confused, because it seems to me that at the end of the code, it should have just stayed at readLine() instead of spitting out "null"s. Does the JVM or class Socket simply determine when the OutputStream has been ended, by looking ahead and seeing that no more writing through println() will occur?

Is my interpretation of println() and readLine() from a Socket's stream correct, and if so, what causes the sudden shift to spitting "null"s? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looping through an writing a bunch of null values. Really just empty Strings.

Comment: @3kings That would cause `readLine()` to return empty strings, not nulls.

Answer (score 4):

> What triggers a Socket's InputStream to close (or reach end of stream), and simply yield null?

1. The only thing that triggers an `InputStream` to close is calling `close()` on it, or on its underlying socket.
2. What triggers an `InputStream` to reach end of stream is reading to end of file in the case of a file, or the peer closing the connection in the case of a socket.
3. `InputStream` doesn't return null, but `BufferedReader.readLine()` does, when you reach end of stream, as it says in the Javadoc.

Possibly you are unaware that closing either the input stream or output stream of a socket will close the socket.

> this code produced an endless stream of "null"

That's because you ignored end of stream. When you get this condition you should close the socket and stop reading.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you closed the socket on the other side

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11924701)

Comment: @SharpEdge You are mistaken. This is not only an answer, it is a correct answer.

Comment: @EJP its too short. Some explanation would have helped. Nonetheless it was in the review of "low quality posts".

Comment: @SharpEdge The VLQ review queue appears to work on word count, or character count. The idea is that you *review*, not just mindlessly agree. 'Too short' is entirely in the eye of the beholder. The relevant fact appears in the answer.

Comment: I didn't mindlessly agree. I still stand on my statement that the answer seems too short, your answer on the other hand has some explanation. I will have to go through the stack overflow faqs and meta for this. And just for the record, i didn't downvote his answer.

Comment: @SharpEdges Nobody has claimed you did. Just for the record. There is a bias here against short answers but it doesn't really make sense. Sometimes the answer is just 'yes'. Or 'no'.